# Oracle SQL - Compare Columns - SELECT records for values that do not have a match

Tags: sql, oracle, search, compare, match

**BACKGROUND**:
Most of the scripts I write search for records that are missing data.    I use the common values in XXXX_APPL_NO (`WHERE XXXX_APPL_NO = YYYY_APPL_NO` ) to make sure the data I select is from the correct row(s).
The APPL_NO will have multiple rows for a record if the person has several applications.
If XXXX_APPL_NO is not equal to YYYY_APPL_NO (because data is missing), the script will ignore the row(s).  So I cannot use `WHERE XXXX_APPL_NO = YYYY_APPL_NO`
I have to **trick** it into giving me the data I want.  I believe I have thought out the process to retrieve it, but I just don't know how to code it!

**Here is the actual data.  NOTE: I do not know what is in the blank fields.  The constraint is "NOT NULL" so I believe there is something there, I just don't know what it is!**
[image: Actual Data with Data Types and Constraints]

Here is my current code:

```
Select distinct 
sp.spriden_id as "ID", 
SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME as "Last", 
SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME as "First",
SA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY as "App Term",  
SA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE as "Adm Type",
st.SARAATT_TERM_CODE,
st.SARAATT_APPL_NO,
sa.SARADAP_APPL_NO
/* I want to make a column in my report ONLY - NOT IN THE DATABASE - 
to print out "No WSP" if there is no corresponding SARAATT_APPL_NO 
for the SARADAP_APPL_NO  */

FROM 
SPRIDEN SP
JOIN SARADAP SA
on sp.spriden_pidm = sa.saradap_PIDM
JOIN SORLCUR SR
on sp.spriden_pidm = SR.SORLCUR_PIDM
full outer JOIN SARAATT ST
on sp.spriden_pidm = ST.SARAATT_PIDM

Where 
Sp.spriden_change_ind is null
AND
SA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE in ('SP', 'XT' )
```

This is the data returned with my current code.  Notice that the Term_Codes and Appl_Nos do NOT match:
[image: Data - No app number match condition]

**Please Note:**  If I add `st.SARAATT_APPL_NO = sa.SARADAP_APPL_NO` to the WHERE clause, it will skip all rows with missing data!  (I need **all** the data so I can weed out what I do not need)
This is the data returned if I add `st.SARAATT_APPL_NO = sa.SARADAP_APPL_NO`.
[image: Data - with app number condition]

In order to retrieve the data I need, I want to do something like this:
SELECT all the data from current SELECT statement.
Then, for each SARADAP_APPL_NO, find the match for it in SARAATT_APPL_NO.
`SELECT` the rows for those that do not have a match, and print “No WSP” in a column I create JUST for the report (not in the database).
This is what I mean by "does it have a match?":
[image: Does it have a match?]

Or could I do some sort of
`SARADAP_APPL_NO not in (SARAATT_APPL_NO)` for a certain spriden_id?
i.e.    `3 4        not in (2 3 4 5)`
If any of SARAATT_AAPL_NO values (2 3 4 5) are not included in SARADAP_APPL_NO values (3 4), it will select the rows for 2 5 of SARAATT_APPL_NO and print out “No WSP” in a column I make for the report.

Do I match?  compare?  search?

These are the results I want:
[image: Desired Results]

**Can I do something like this and add it somewhere in the code?  I want to first SELECT the data then LOOP through what I have selected.**

```
DECLARE
SARADAP_Count number() = 0;
SARAATT_Count number() = 0;

/* to keep going through the SARAATT_APPL_NO column until the end */
WHILE SA.SARADAP_APPL_NO not null 
    LOOP
    /*  If value being looked at in SARADAP = the value being looked at in SARAATT */
    IF SARADAP_APPL_NO = st.SARAATT_APPL_NO  
        /*  Then add 1 to the count so we can compare the next value in SARADAP  with the values in SARAATT*/
        THEN SARADAP_Count = SARADAP_Count + 1 
        /*  Otherwise add 1 to the count to look at the next SARAATT value*/
        ELSE SARAATT_Count = SARAATT_Count + 1; 
        /* when we  have compared all the values in SARAATT for one SARADAP value, and no     values matched, then print 'No WSP' in the "My Report Column" */ 
        WHEN SARADAP_APPL_NO <> st.SARAATT_APPL_NO THEN return 'NO WSP' in "MY REPORT COLUMN" 
        /* Now go to the next SARADAP row to compare that value with the values in SARAATT */ 
            LOOP
            SARADAP_Count = SARADAP_Count +1 /*  */
                END LOOP
    END LOOP
```

**____________________________________________________________________________________**

1. There are two main tables I am working with: SARADAP and SARAATT.  SARADAP is the actual admission application.  SARAATT contains attributes and has common fields with the application (SARAATT/SARADAP _PIDM, SARAATT/SARADAP _TERM_CODE, and SARAATT/SARADAP _APPL_NO)
2. The 3rd table is SPRIDEN and contains biographical information for the person. I only need the ID from that table.
3. My SELECT statement includes the TERM_CODE and APPL_NO columns for both main tables, but the WHERE clauses contain no conditions that would make the TERM_CODEs or APPL_NOs from both tables match.  This means that instead of the rows being consistent (as they are in the image below), the query just gathers the information and puts it in the printout however it wants.
4. Problem: If I add a condition (`SARADAP_APPL_NO = st.SARAATT_APPL_NO` and `SARADAP_TERM_CODE = st.SARAATT_TERM_CODE`), the information I **really** need will not be selected.
5. What I really need is for the query to tell me where SARAATT_ATTS_CODE has nothing in the row that corresponds to the APPL_NO or TERM_CODE.  I cannot get that information because SARAATT_ATTS_CODE has "nothing" in it for that row and is therefore ignored by the query.  It has a NOT NULL constraint, so I cannot simply search for NULL values.  (This is the real problem I am trying to work around by doing a `LOOP` or something)
6. Since the query will not return the results I need (show me where the ATTS_CODE is unpopulated), My work-round idea was to look at both APPL_NO columns and find look for values that are NOT in BOTH columns.  Those would be the people who have an unpopulated SARAATT_ATTS_CODE row.
   **This is the actual DATA that is in the database (but I have added the My Column just to show what I want to print**
   [image: Data]

**These are the results from my current query**
[image: Current Query Results]

**toddlermenot, you asked for the results of the Toddlerminot query within the WITH clause:**
[image: Results from WITH Clause]
I sorted the results by SARADAP_APPL_NO.  Notice that the data in red is mixed up.  It's not really where it should be and 200810 and 201510 terms are missing as well as the corresponding appl numbers (2 and 5).  This is when the query is just looking for any value existing in that table (I believe it is using the next available value) and placing it in that row since there is actually nothing in that row -- or the query is not matching the APPPL numbers and TERMS with each other.

**Results from the Toddlerminot query as a whole** 
[image: Results from Entire Toddlerminot Query]
I sorted the results by SARADAP_APPL_NO.

I will now try to "create a small example like the one [Toddlerminot] posted in sqlfiddle to illustrate the problem [I am] facing. I will add it to my question.

I did it in Fiddle. sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4d10/2 Please note that I put in ' ' for the blank values because there is a not null constraint.  I think it is actually now http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa83f/1 since I edited it again.  I changed the datatype to Number(2,0) and entered 0 instead of ' '

**This is how the tables are, and this is the data that is in each table for Maria Smith.**
[image: Tables and Corresponding Data]

Comment: Per your post title; you can simply do like `select * from your_table where columna not in (select distinct columnb from your_table)`

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for your reply.  I am not sure what you mean.  There are a total of 4 columns involved.  The two columns I want to compare/match/search are `st.SARAATT` and `sa.SARADAP`.

Comment: @Rahul I added `SA.SARADAP_APPL_NO not in (SELECT DISTINCT st.SARAATT_APPL_NO FROM SARAATT ST)` but no rows were selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 3:**
Using the data model you posted, I have constructed this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1665/10

Let me know if this works out for you.

Couple of things:

- All 4 rows in SPRIDEN are duplicates. So kept only one.
- Table SORLCUR is used nowhere and not in the posted screenshot. So nuked it from the query.
- Couple of columns referenced are nowhere to be found in the posted screenshot. So nuked them from the query.
- Data discrepancy that you highlighted is caused because of cartesian join due to leaving out the TERM_CODE in the join condition.
- Report Column works as intended.

---

Looks like you want a pseudo-column for reporting.

If I parsed your question correctly, below should do the trick:

**EDIT:** Based on your comment/edit, I have updated the query:

**EDIT 2:** 
It is still hard to say without the entire data model, but if I understand correctly there are 2 problems:

1 - Data highlighted in Red: My guess -> this is because of using a FULL OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN. Updated this is in the code below. Try and let me know.

2 - "My Report Column" coming as blank: Haven't got a clue why this isn't working, your SQL fiddle seems to show it work.

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            SP.SPRIDEN_ID AS "ID", 
            SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME AS "LAST", 
            SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME AS "FIRST",
            SA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY AS "APP_TERM",  
            SA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE AS "ADM_TYPE",
            ST.SARAATT_TERM_CODE AS "TERM_CODE",
            ST.SARAATT_APPL_NO "APPL_NO1",
            SA.SARADAP_APPL_NO "APPL_NO2"
    FROM 
        SPRIDEN SP
        JOIN SARADAP SA
        ON SP.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SA.SARADAP_PIDM
        JOIN SORLCUR SR
        ON SP.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SR.SORLCUR_PIDM
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SARAATT ST
        ON SP.SPRIDEN_PIDM = ST.SARAATT_PIDM
    WHERE 
        SP.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
        AND SA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE IN ('SP', 'XT' )
)
SELECT
    ID,
    LAST,
    FIRST,
    APP_TERM,
    ADM_TYPE,
    TERM_CODE,
    APPL_NO1,
    APPL_NO2,
    CASE
    WHEN (SELECT
           COUNT(1)
         FROM
           t t2
         WHERE
           t1.APPL_NO2=t2.APPL_NO1) = 0 THEN 'NO WSP'
    END AS "My Report Column"
FROM
    t t1;
```

I haven't tested this for syntactic errors, so feel free to correct them. I am sure there is an analytic function solution for this, but I think this should work just as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I cannot test it until I am at work tomorrow.  This is what I need: Look in both columns ST.SARAATT_APPL_NO & SA.SARADAP_APPL_NO.  Find that rows SARADAP_APPL_NO= 2 and SARADAP_APPL_NO=5 do not have matches in any of the SARAATT_APPL_NO rows.  Pull those rows that do not have a match.    
I will test this tomorrow.  I hope you will check back. :)

Comment: @AuntieAnita: Sure, check and let me know. The above query will NOT filter out the records which have SARAATT_APPL_NO = SARADAP_APPL_NO. Instead it will display ALL the records (as you stated in your question) with the required records (ie., SARADAP_APPL_NO <> SARAATT_APPL_NO) having the 'No WSP' value while the others will have NULL for "My Report Column".

Comment: :(  If the two columns literally do not match, it puts NO WSP.  It needs to do this:  look at value in Column 2, Row 1 (C2R1) is the value somewhere in C1?  No, print "NO WSP" in `My Report Column` -- C2R2 in C1? no, print No WSP -- C2R3 in C1? Yes, print nothing, etc...  
So, it needs to look at each value in C2, see if it is in C1 then decide whether or not to print "No WSP"

Comment: I added another image explaining what I am hoping to make work.  I believe what I am asking will make the script run slowly, but it's the only way I can think of that will return the data I need.  Also, once I take away  the APPL_NO and SARAATT term columns from the SELECT statement, it will eliminate all the duplicate rows and leave me with exactly what I want.

Comment: @AuntieAnita: Updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks.  The `My Report Column` was blank - it did not output "No WSP" for any of the rows.  At the bottom of my initial post, I added some pseudo code  for the loop I think may work.  Do you think something like that could work?

Comment: @AuntieAnita: Are you sure about that? Here is a simplified example that shows that it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d40245/3 About the code you posted, I think this would be better done in SQL from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Sadly, the report Column was blank :-(  Is it looking at the results from the SELECT statement or is it going back to the database and looking at that information? The difference may be that the values in the two APPL_NO columns are not hard-coded.  Since I do not require the Term_Codes to be equal, the query randomly selects the APPL_NOs.  (Each APPL_NO has a corresponding Term_CODE)  If you look at the terms, you will see they do not match.  This is the only way I can trick it into giving me the data I need. I am sorry. I am a newb in SQL. I have been working on this problem for over a week.

Comment: In a perfect world, the two APPL_NO columns would have matching numbers, and the TERM_CODE columns would have matching terms. In this instance, they cannot be allowed to so that I can return all data.  BTW, thank you for posting SQLFiddle! I did not know about that! :-)

Comment: @AuntieAnita I am not sure what you mean by "randomly selects". I see no randomness in the SQL. SQL results are designed to be deterministic. Anyways, please post results of the query within the WITH clause and the query as a whole. This will enable the debugging process a whole lot easier. Also if possible, create a small example like the one I posted in sqlfiddle to illustrate the problem you are facing.

Comment: I have added a lot to my question - it starts near the bottom where I have drawn a  line ____________________________  I will try to do the fiddler now and post that too.  Fiddler did not work because you did not know that the actual dataset contained blank fields.

Comment: I did it in Fiddle.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4d10/2 Please note that I put in ' ' for the blank values because there is a not null constraint.   If I want the query to select certain data then with that selected data, put additional conditions, can I have another nested select?  Or is the WITH clause sort of like a nested select?

Comment: @AuntieAnita: Thanks for providing the details. Please refer to my EDIT 2

Comment: Well, it is in red because I pasted the data into MS Excel, sorted it by APPL_No, then colored it red to signify the places where the data was just sort of thrown in the results in no particular order. :(  I'm sorry to be confusing.  The Left Outer Join had the same results.  It is different in Fiddle because in my database, those rows (for APPL_No 2 and 5) do not exist. :(  That is my whole problem:  I need to know when they do not exist.  and "not exists" will not work.  I am sorry to take so much of your time.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AuntieAnita: Please post a SSCCE in sqlfiddle illustrating your problem. Without the exact(simplified) simulation, I am afraid we'll be speculating endlessly on *WHAT* your problem is. Please read up on http://sscce.org/ to know what SSCCE is. As the article says, this will increase your chance of finding the solution.

Comment: Thank you.  I will read that.  In the meantime, this may help!  I have included an image of the three tables and the data they contain for Maria Smith.  This may also help since it shows what is in all three tables.

Comment: I would like to mark your answer so you receive credit (although I posted a different answer).  There is a lot in what you said that solved problems I was having.  Is it okay if I mark your answer as correct?  Thanks!!!  EDIT:  Ah!  yes, yours was the "most helpful in helping me find a solution!"

Answer (score 0):

** Thank you to Todderlmenot (https://stackoverflow.com/users/350136/toddlermenot) for all his time and effort!  You helped me solve one half of the problem and learn a lot in the process!
Also, thank you to Vignesh Lakshmirajan for helping me solve the other half of the problem**

It turns out that I can use `MINUS` to determine the rows that are missing from a column.

```
/*
Author: 
Date: 30-Sep-14
Purpose: Select records of Special or Transient applicants whose Attribute field (SAAADMS - Contacts, Cohorts, Attributes) does contain "WSP"

NOTE: For those records missing the WSP, there will be no rows in SARAATT for the term/application number in which WPS is missing.  
Those rows will simply not exist.   

SARADAP_TERM    SARADAP_APPL    SARAATT_TERM    SARAATT_APPL    SARAATT_ATTS_CODE    
    200810          2               200810          2               WPS
    200910          3                       
    201080          4               201080          4               WPS
    201350          5                    

Use SARADAP MINUS SARAATT to retreive the rows for which there is no SARAATT.  
We can use this becuase for rows in which there is no WSP, there will also be no APPL_NO or TERM_CODE       
*/



Select  
sp.spriden_id as "ID", 
SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME as "Last", 
SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME as "First", 
SA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY as "SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY",  
sa.SARADAP_APPL_NO as "SARADAP_APPL_NO"

FROM     
SPRIDEN SP
JOIN SARADAP SA
on sp.spriden_pidm = sa.saradap_PIDM

WHERE 
Sp.spriden_change_ind is null
AND
SA.SARADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY >= '201510'
AND
SA.SARADAP_ADMT_CODE in ('SP', 'XT' )


MINUS


SELECT
sp.spriden_id as "ID", 
SP.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME as "Last", 
SP.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME as "First",
st.SARAATT_TERM_CODE as "SARAATT_TERM_CODE",
st.SARAATT_APPL_NO as "SARAATT_APPL_NO"

FROM 
SPRIDEN SP
LEFT OUTER JOIN SARAATT ST
on sp.spriden_pidm = ST.SARAATT_PIDM

WHERE 
Sp.spriden_change_ind is null
```